# crawl requestes in FIFO order with scrapy

Tags: scrapy

i want scrapy to process the crawl in FIFO order, for example i have a loop in that loop each element process 3 DEPTH nodes, the second element start after completed the first one with 3 DEPTH calls.

Comment: Maybe [this section from the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would solve this is to put all the data that is needed to make a  request in meta and have a parsing function that would handle 2 cases.

First case would handle "3 levels deep and the logic" and things related to that and the second case would be parsing the the main page.

After You have done that simply return a request to call the same function again.

General idea is to have all the "next step" information in meta and act on that information to separate the cases.

Comment: That's what i did, but in this way it might affect concurrency